# Remove "-" after binary operation

Tags: python, binary

This is my code:

```
with open("bin.bin", "rb") as file:
    content=file.read()
    binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(content), 16))
    binary = ' '.join('{0:08b}'.format(ord(x)-128, 'b') for x in content)
    print binary
```

My output is in the form:

```
01100111 -1001001 00011110
```

How can I get rid of the "-" and replace it by 0?

Comment: You possibly want `(ord(x) + 128) % 256`? But it's unclean why you would want anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're trying to actually get the bits right (rather than just trying to center the values), you need a different strategy.  `-1001001` is actually `-73`.  For an 8-bit quantity, the twos complement version of this would actually be `10110111`--which is what the below does:

```
def convert_num(num, bits=8):
    if num >= 0:
        return num
    mask = (1 << bits) - 1
    return ((-1 * num) ^ 0xFF) + 1

binary = ' '.join('{0:08b}'.format(convert_num(ord(x)-128), 'b') for x in content)
```

However, if the data that you're reading is meant to be signed, then you can use `struct.unpack()` to convert the data:

```
binary  =' '.join('{0:08b}'.format(struct.unpack('b', x)[0], 'b') for x in content)
```

Or you can use this instead:

```
def to_signed_char(x):
    if x >= 128:
        return x - 256
    return x

binary = ' '.join('{0:08b}'.format(to_signed_char(x), 'b') for x in content)
```

It really depends on what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, just found the answer, just added abs()

```
binary  =' '.join('{0:08b}'.format(abs(ord(x)-128), 'b') for x in content)
```

Comment: Do you realize that you're not representing the same quantity in binary with that representation?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean you're representing -73 as `01001001` which is the same as 73.  The twos complement version (signed char) would be `10110111`.

Comment: I just want to convert the output to ascii so I need to get rid of the "-" so, what is the ascii representation for "-0101000" ? is that "00101000" ?

Comment: "-0101000" is -73, but it's a non-standard form (Python did this to make things easier for non-compsci folks, but it's a bit confusing).  The actual bits stored in the machine are actually `10110111`.  Perhaps it would be better to explain what the data is, and then we can help determine what the correct approach should be.

Comment: Thanks, just used the function convert_num and it works perfectly :)